# A BaseActivity for all activities, possible?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

There are methods and attributes I would like to share across activities. E.g.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
```

would be the parent for another activity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
```

BUT if the child activity is a e.g. ListActivity this is not possible, right? Do I need a base class for ListActivity, too? This would be redundant code.

I could transform the ListActivity to an Activity, but this would be more code then necessary.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean with redundant?

Comment: @blackbelt I share the same methods for activity and list activity but for list activity I would need another base class with the same methods as the other base class and this would lead to redundancy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're right. As java does not support multiple inheritance, a class can only have one base class.

But you can work via delegation instead of inheritance: Put your methods into a separate class (which does NOT inherit `Activity`) and use instances of it in your activities. Then you can reduce the redundant code (creating and holding the instance) to a minimum.

See also:

http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-inheritance-with-delegation

[How do I implement multiple inheritence in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917190/how-do-i-implement-multiple-inheritence-in-java)

Comment: perfect solution, thumbs up!!

Answer (score 4):

For the `ListActivity` case I would create a `BaseListActivity` that extends from `BaseActivity`. The `BaseListActivity` would contain a `getListView()` that returns the `ListView` if you really-really need it, a protected method `setAdapter()` that receives an `Adapter`/`ListAdapter`. You could also create some protected methods for enabling to show the empty view, to enable this behavior and to return the ids for your empty view and ListView. By default these should point to `android.R.id.list`/`android.R.id.empty`. But you can override that in your child activity. 
In the end it's a matter of OOP and not that much of Android specific. If you check the implementation of [ListActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java) you'll see how simple it is to make your own `BaseListActivity` implementation. In the end it's more important to have a consistent and robust class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I am using my `Activities` this way, and I'm really happy I'm doing it. Of course you have to make some changes (like the `ListActivity` you mentioned in your question), but it has more advantages then disadvantages in my opinion.

In my app I don't have to worry about sending Analytics data every time I create a new `Activity`, and I also don't have to worry about setting up `BroadcastReceiver`s I need in every class, I just made my `BaseActivity` abstract and have an abstract function what I call every time my `BaseActivity` gets a broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share some methods the best way it to impelement an interface or make an abstract class for baseactivty.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to use composition, since multiple inheritance is not possible in Java. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9087284/1772556) to a related question explains how to do this in the case of Android Activities.