# How do I bypass this multiple inheritance problem?

Tags: java, inheritance

I can't find a solution to this inheritance problem. I'm working on a program which will store information about celestial bodies. I have an abstract superclass, `Body`, from which all other celestial bodies should inherit. Now, I want some bodies to have implementation by default for storing information about orbiting bodies; some bodies should be `Orbitable` and some should be `Orbital`. e.g. a Star is `orbitable` only, a Planets and Moons are both `orbitable` and `orbital`, and an Asteroid is `orbital` only.

```
public abstract class Orbital {

    Body host;

    protected double avgOrbitalRadius;
    protected double orbitalPeriod;

    public double getOrbitalRadius(){return this.avgOrbitalRadius;}
    public double getOrbitalPeriod(){return this.orbitalPeriod;}

}
```

```
public abstract class Orbitable {

    List<Body> satellites = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addSatellite(Body sat){
        satellites.add(sat);
    }

    public boolean hasSatellite(Body sat){
        for(Body body : satellites){
            if(sat.equals(body)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasSatellite(String satName){
        for(Body body : satellites){
            if(satName.equals(body.getName())) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Body getSatellite(String satName){
        for(Body body : satellites){
            if(satName.equals(body.getName())) return body;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to have objects be able to inherit one, both, or neither of the above implementations (plus the `Body` superclass which describes the foundation for any celestial body).
I've tried using interfaces with default methods but the key problem is that the implementation involves reading or modifying the object's state, which cannot be implemented with interfaces because all variables in an interface are implicitly static.

I've also viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081818/bypass-multiple-inheritance-in-java) post about very similar issues, but the inheritance of state is causing me grief.

So, how can I solve this multiple inheritance problem? Is it even possible in Java? Are there other designs that could circumvent this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you learn about the [Galactic year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_year).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create Interfaces `Orbitable` and `Orbital`, that define (but obviously do not implement) methods for the state manipulations you want to have.

---

2. Create three (abstract) classes

   - `OrbitableBody extends Body implements Orbitable`
   - `OrbitalBody extends Body implements Orbital`
   - `OrbitableOrbitalBody extends Body implements Orbitable, Orbital`

   And make those three classes realize the methods from the interfaces.

---

3. Make your celestial bodies extend the fitting class out of the four: `Body`, `OrbitableBody`, `OribtalBody` or `OrbitableOrbitalBody`.

---

They will then all be a Body, implement the correct interfaces, and
    inherit default implementations for the interface-defined methods.

Comment: So `OrbitableOrbitalBody` will just repeat all the code from `OrbitalBody` and `OrbitableBody` and every change you make you will need to remember to make in both?

Comment: Well, you could make `OrbitableOrbitalBody extends OrbitableBody implements Orbital` or the way around, then you'd only have to repeat a part of it. But avoiding duplication entirely is impossible in Java. While Java has Traits in the form of default implementations in interfaces, it does not have non-static properties in interfaces, so this will not work for the OP.

Comment: @Oleg - there is a way around that by using [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in interfaces. Depending on your other needs sometimes abstract base classes with `final` methods in combination with default interface methods can help.

Comment: @StephenP See my comment - while Java does have default implementations for methods, you cannot specify default properties in intrefaces, so you can't store any state.

Comment: So the solution is to add another layer of abstraction? As a student, I haven't yet had to create large hierarchies like this, so this is a novel solution to me. Thank you!

Comment: in Java, yes, this is the only solution for this kind of problem. Other concepts, such as fully-featured traits for example, do exist, but java has not implemented them.

Comment: @Octa:
@JohannesH. has designed a very good OOP solution for your need. As they have suggested, you can definitely take advantage of `default` methods right in the interfaces (e.g. `rotate()`, `move()`). Something that did not exist in the early days of Java when a lot of OOP knowledge-base was being explored.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
Let me approach this classic object oriented pattern problem with some visual help.

I would have two interfaces namely:

```
Orbitable
Orbital
```

Then a base class `Body`. You can make it **concrete** or **abstract** depending on your implementation details. For example you can add behaviors like *does it have an atmosphere?* in the form of method `hasAtmosphere()`. This can be `abstract` first and then have your implementing classes override this.

Then I will have two additional  sub-classes extending `Body` and implementing each interface (remember interface separates responsibility by providing contracts for behaviors)

```
BaseOrbitable
BaseOrbital
BaseOrbitalOrbitable
```

Finally some concrete (sub-classes) implementation examples:

```
public class Earth extends Planet {
}
```

or

```
public class Ceres extends Asteroid {
}
```

or

```
public class Sirius extends BaseOrbitable {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Johannes H. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61625465/1398418) is relatively simple and might be a good solution. It has a problem of code duplication though. Instead I suggest to think of `Orbital` and `Orbitable` as something your celestial bodies have and use composition and delegation:

```
class Body {
}

interface Orbital {
    public double getOrbitalRadius();
}

interface Orbitable {
    public void addSatellite(Body sat);
}

// Default common implementation, shouldn't be abstract
class OrbitalImpl implements Orbital {
    protected double avgOrbitalRadius;
    public double getOrbitalRadius(){return this.avgOrbitalRadius;}
    // ...
}

class OrbitableImpl implements Orbitable {
    List<Body> satellites = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addSatellite(Body sat){satellites.add(sat);}
    //...
}

class OrbitableOrbitalBody extends Body implements Orbitable, Orbital {
    Orbitable orbitable;
    Orbital orbital;

    public OrbitableOrbitalBody() {
        orbitable = new OrbitableImpl();
        orbital = new OrbitalImpl();
    }

    public OrbitableOrbitalBody(Orbitable orbitable, Orbital orbital) {
        this.orbitable = orbitable;
        this.orbital = orbital;
    }

    @Override
    public double getOrbitalRadius() {
        return orbital.getOrbitalRadius();
    }

    @Override
    public void addSatellite(Body sat) {
        orbitable.addSatellite(sat);
    }
} 

class OrbitableBody extends Body implements Orbitable {
    Orbitable orbitable;

    // Use default implementation
    public OrbitableBody() {
        orbitable = new OrbitableImpl();
    }

    // If needed use orbitable that behaves differently
    public OrbitableBody(Orbitable orbitable) {
        this.orbitable = orbitable;
    }

    // delegate to orbitable
    @Override
    public void addSatellite(Body sat) {
        orbitable.addSatellite(sat);
    }
}

// Same as Orbitable
//class OrbitalBody extends Body implements Orbital {
```

Comment: I like this solution too. So, because you can't extend multiple classes, instead you possess instances of those classes to utilize both their implementations. I like it, it's just weird to think of properties as something that are possessed rather than intrinsic. As for addressing code duplication though, it seems like one would still have to provide implementation for all three implementing classes? E.g addSatellite to both OrbitableBody and OrbitableOrbitalBody. How does this solution deal with code duplicarion and, as you mentioned, the problem of needing to make changes in multiple places?

Comment: The only thing that is duplicated is a one line delegated method call. This is something you usually need to do only once and if there will be a change in the contract (`Orbitable`) you will know exactly what changes you need to make because you will get compilation errors. The actual implementation is in `OrbitableImpl` and it's not duplicated.